# Custom Table Visual in Power BI

Tags: powerbi

I am looking to make changes in the [sampleBarChart](https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-visuals-sampleBarChart) visual to create a custom visual table.

I have come across [this post](http://community.powerbi.com/t5/Developer/developing-Custom-Visual-with-Table-Data-Binding/m-p/74693) and looked at several repos in Github to find how this can be done. I am able to bring the data in the dataView but could not figure out how to build visual out of it. Here is the **capabilities.json:**

```
{
    "dataRoles": [{
        "displayName": "Values",
        "name": "Values",
        "kind": "Grouping"
    }],
    "dataViewMappings": [{
    "table": {
        "rows": {
            "select": [{"for": {"in": "Values"}}]
        }
    }
  }]
}
```

[image: dataView]

The data is there but how to create a table visual in **visual.ts**?

Once the table is created and data is rendered in columns and rows, my objective would be to transpose it and create individual rows for each column.

[image: table]
 **to**
[image]

Comment: I strongly advise having a look at [this tutorial](https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-visuals) if you haven't already.

Comment: I had some good answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39534813/developing-powerbi-visuals) as well.